# Recommendations on plotting a graph

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, graph

[image]

I need to draw a graph like the one shown above in my application. The values for Y axis is updated periodically which is obtained from an electronic device and X axis refers to time elapsed . By default, the viewing range of X axis is automatically updated (extends horizontally) as seconds elapse.

One thing I find pretty challenging right off the bat is, users can also manually set the range of X and Y axis, so I need to come up with a flexible way to handle that part.

Can I get some recommendations on handling the above requirements? I prefer WPF but Winforms is fine too. Are there any example projects which solves a problem similar to above? 
Or any third-party dlls I can use (for commercial purposes)?

Comment: I suggest you use an ready-made charting control like the one from DevExpress: http://demos.devexpress.com/XtraChartsDemos/

Comment: If you want to go WPF this article might interest you : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx (but still, +1 for what Daniel Hilgarth said)

Comment: There's an example of realtime charting with the Microsoft charting components here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297119%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (snag is it's in F# so I'll see if I can dig out a C# version for you). They ship free with .Net 4 so it's probably worth exploring their usage - the DevExpress charting controls are good, but are not free.

Comment: I would prefer controls that are for free. Thanks for the recommendations!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456769.aspx, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization. Also, consider publishing the data to Perfmon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I'm considering switching to right now is simply embedding a web control in whatever type of application (winforms, wpf) and then using html/javascript to draw the graph using an opensource library such as : [flotr2](http://coderbay.com/free-html5-and-javascript-charting-library-flotr2/), [Style Chart](http://chart.inetsoft.com/), [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/), [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/) and [D3](http://d3js.org/).  The benefit of doing it this way is that if you decide to change platforms your graphing doesn't need to change.

Right now I'm using [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/), which is a WPF graphing library.

Answer (score 1):

winforms:

.NET3.5 onwards has chart controls built in (I think)

Im new to this too but you have to create the chart control and then create a series object with the data. Then the update the chart control with the series that contains your data.

There is a sample project here:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418